# Pentaho Job - Evaluate a condition to determine where to send job flow

Tags: pentaho, etl

I have a Pentaho job and in the job itself I want to evaluate a condition and send the job in one of two directions based on the result of that condition. In particular, I want to see whether the time's hour is "3" (i.e. between 3 and 4 a.m.) and if it is, send it in one direction, and if not, in the other direction.

What is the easiest way to do this? (I am using Pentaho 4.2 Spoon)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A transformation is one option - as "Working Hard" said.

If you want to evaluate a condition in the job itself, you can use the "simple evaluation"-step in the job.

To do so, check the field-value of the time (important: it should have the date-format HH:mm) with the condition "If value is between".

It could look like this:
[image]

(if you get problems like Pentaho is asking for a field or something like that, just add a comment)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any specific constrain then you can create 1 transformation and execute that transformation to job..

in transformation after you will get your desired output you can use **"modified java-script"** step and their you can check for condition for the same that if it is satisfying your condition then send to A step if not then B step.